# Home folder not writeable

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, users, home-directory

I have two users, and one of them can't write to his home directory (but the desktop directory?!) and Thunar displays a lock on the home folder. However, if I run `ls -l` in `/home`, I get

```
drwxr-xr-x 28 habefaro habefaro 4096 Mär  4  2013 habefaro
drwxr-xr-x 22 psirus   psirus   4096 Apr  4 16:52 psirus
```

So I can't see the difference?! Btw, habefaro is the user who can't write to his home folder.

**EDIT:** Running `sudo lsattr -d /home/habefaro` gives

```
----i--------e-- habefaro/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the `lsattr` output, the user's home directory has been marked as *immutable* which will mean that no files or directories may be added or deleted. You should be able to unset the immutable attribute using `chattr` i.e.

```
sudo chattr -i /home/habefaro/
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the user has no permission on some subdirectories in the home?

Correct the owner permissions with:

```
sudo chown -R habefaro:habefaro /home/habefaro
```

With this command, the user habefaro will become the owner of all the files and folders in his home directory.

Comment: I've run the command, and all the subdirectories are owned by habefaro. However, on `/home/habefaro` it fails with `Operation is not permitted.`

Comment: `Operation is not permitted` usually indicates the presence of extended file attributes - can you run `sudo lsattr -d` on the directory and add the result to your question please?

Comment: @steeldriver See edit.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the folder permissions are not correct.
Set home permission to default (0775): this set also subdirectories

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/habefaro/
```

Comment: Again, it fails on `/home/habefaro` with `Operation is not permitted.`

Comment: In any case, `find /home/habefaro -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` would be better since you may not want to change the file permissions if it's only the directories which are not writable.